# Tracking goals with the same destination URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have three goals that have the same destination URL. They all have different funnels but report the same number of conversions in the past 7 days in the Admin > Goals screen. When I verify the goal they all have the same percentage of completions. If I look at the goal funnel visualization it will show different numbers as the final outcome over what I believe is the same past 7 days for each goal.

Shouldn't the outcome of the goal funnel visualization be the same conversion number on the Admin > Goals screen?

Is the tracking of what's on the Admin > Goals screen past 7 day conversions and the final value of the goal funnel visualization just inherently different?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related (but to save you the search, funnel visualization does not affect conversion, and goals with the same destination url are counted regardless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all reports you will see the same number of Goal Completions and CR for all your 3 goals.

Only in report 'Funnel Visualization' you will see conversions for each funnel separately.

Answer (score 0):

The Funnel Visualization has a logic of its own, read the documentation for differences with the most reliable Goal Flow in Analytics:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en

Here you will find more information about the inconsistencies of the Funnel Visualization:

https://www.analyticstraps.com/stesso-obiettivo-ma-totale-completamento-diverso/
https://www.analyticstraps.com/quando-la-visualizzazione-canalizzazione-mente/